# Fechar conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me tirar a seguinte dúvida, eu faço a conexão com o banco de dados em PHP dessa forma:

```
$conexao = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $nomeBanco);
```

E fecho a conexao com `$conexao->close();`. Se eu utilizo `$conexao->query($sql)` várias vezes em minha página é necessario um `$conexao->close();` para cada uma  ou esse método já comporta todas as chamadas?

Comment: Erick, caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema você pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Ou, caso queira, pode deixar em aberto mais um tempo se deseja mais alternativas, mas é bom que depois de resolvida você marque alguma para fechar o assunto. Saiba mais em ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Comment: Muito Obrigado meu amigo! Sua contribuição foi de grande ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Se eu utilizo `$conexao->query($sql)` várias vezes em minha página é
>   necessário um `$conexao->close();` para cada uma ou esse método já
>   comporta todas as chamadas?

Não é necessário fechar a conexão para cada `$conexao->query($sql)`. Até porque, pense comigo, se eu abro uma conexão e executo uma *query* e logo após a mesma já fecho a conexão, se eu tentar executar outra *query* o PHP vai mostra erro por justamente não ter conexão aberta com o banco de dados.

Para exemplificar imagine um banco de dados aleátorio. Vamos abrir uma conexão com ele, mostrar os dados, executar uma *query*, fechar a conexão e tentar executar novamente outra *query*.

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

var_dump($conexao); // Mostrará alguns dados da conexão

mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tabela (coluna) VALUES ('Teste')");

mysqli_close($conexao); // Fecho a conexção

mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tabela (coluna) VALUES ('Teste depois da conexão')");
```

Ao executar a primeira *query* terei sucesso e o valor será inserido, já a a segunda query não será inserido e irá retornar um *warning*:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in (caminho) on line (linha)

Só relembrando: o `mysqli_close` fecha uma conexão aberta anteriormente com o banco de dados e sempre retorna TRUE no *success* e FALSE no *failure*.

**Referências**

- [Documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-close.php)